# How can I change permissions for a folder and all sub files and folders in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I know there are a few questions on this topic on the internet but I have a slightly different question.

so when I click on the change permissions for enclosed files and change the permissions for others to read and write for files and create and delete files for folders and then I click change. when I click the "change permissions fro enclosed" button the permissions never get saved and they are back to default.

Comment: Not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command line to change the fiolder permission to READ / WRITE / EXECUTION for everyone.

```
chmod -R 777 /file/path/of/the/folder
```

Obviously, you should have permission for the folder of this folder that you are changing.